# How do I link to a site after validation in Javascript and HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How exactly do I link to a different website when the validation is true in javascript?  I am struggling with working out the validation.

Comment: what is "validation"? what is "linking"? what is "true"?

Comment: function validate()
{
var username=document.getElementById("username").value;
var password=document.getElementById("password").value;

if (username=="admin"&& password=="user")
{
    window.open("Reports.html")

}
else{
    alert("Login Failed")
}




}

Comment: is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage an answer?

Comment: that did not help

Comment: define "link to a different website" then

Comment: i got it to work I did not put paranthesis in the html

Answer (score 1):

if you want to locate to other page in javascript you can use  window.location.replace("Reports.html")

Comment: it is not going to the other html page it just stays in the login page

Comment: can you give me code ?